# Not Recommended relay

Tags: relays, flags

I looked up my entry-node in Relay Search(Tor Metrics) and I found additional flags was "Not Recommended".
Should I change my entry-node manually?

Answer (score 0):

The flag *Not Recommended* means that you run a Tor version which is not recommended by the directory authorities. They maintain a [list of recommended versions](https://consensus-health.torproject.org/#recommendedversions). Your version of Tor is probably to old or has some other issues.

Usually it helps to update to the latest version of Tor.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I am just a client and not a entry-node.
I mean, entry-node to which I am connecting.
I apologize for confusing you because of my bad English.

According to ARM,my Tor version is 0.3.5.8(recommended).
Does a client not have to mind entry-node's additional flag?